# Write a function to accept an integer and return a number made up of digits from the input number in ascending order

Tags: java

How can I write a function to accept an `int` and return a number made up of digits from the input number in ascending order? 
Also, if the input is negative, then change the order to descending.

For example:

1. input is 48455, output should be 44558,
2. input is -15243, output should be -54321.

Comment: Done. How did you get on? You know you didn't actually ask a question, right?

Comment: What is your question and what is your current code ?

Comment: I am glad that you shared your assignment with us. I don't think it's neccessary for you to inform us that you are working on some task but the thought is still appreciated. On a more serious note: Your post only contains a paste of a work assignment. No explanations, no question, nothing. Please show effort in solving your question on your own. If you get stuck along the way, we are glad to help you with a specific step.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? Note: you don't actually need to read this as an integer, you could just sort the characters.

Comment: I have the code to it but it's wasn't professional and was not optimized. That's why I thought you'd could provide me a better code. Anyway, I have posted my code as an attempt. Please help me optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code but it's not optimized and so I was asking for better code.

```
public int orderDigits(int a) {
    String str = a + "";
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray);
    if (a>0)
    {

        String Sorted = new String(charArray);
        return Integer.parseInt(Sorted);
    }
    else if (a<0)
    {   
        int size = 1;
        while(a!=0){
            size++;
            a /= 10;
        }
        String tempStr = new String(charArray);
        String withoutMinus = tempStr.substring(1);         
        String withoutZero = withoutMinus.substring(0, withoutMinus.length());
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(withoutZero);
        sb.reverse();
        String revStr = sb + "";            
        return -(Integer.parseInt(revStr));
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my code, at first, you should change and then add the sign of number in order to sort it with successfully via using `Integer.parseInt()`, for this, I have used below codes:

```
    if (number.contains("-")) {
        number = number.replace("-", "");
        System.out.println("-" + Reverse.sortString(initializer(number)));
    }
```

Method `String[] initializer(String num)` is for to convert String literal to String array.

Method `String sortString(String initializer[])` is for to sort String array via using [Bubble sort](https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java) algorithm, as you want, it is important to sort your numbers from big to small numbers.

Method    `String getSortedString(String initializer[])` is for to get sorted String.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {

    static String sortedString = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number");
        //input
        String number = scanner.next();
        //check if input number is negative or positive
        //if negative, remove a sign and add it last.
        //else, do nothing to number
        if (number.contains("-")) {
            number = number.replace("-", "");
            System.out.println("-" + Reverse.sortString(initializer(number)));
        } else {
            System.out.println(Reverse.sortString(initializer(number)));
        }
    }

    //convert String literal to String array
    private static String[] initializer(String num) {
        String arr[] = new String[num.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = "" + num.charAt(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    //sort converted String array with using Bubble sorting
    private static String sortString(String initializer[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < initializer.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < initializer.length; j++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(initializer[j - 1]) < Integer.parseInt(initializer[j])) {
                    String temp = initializer[j - 1];
                    initializer[j - 1] = initializer[j];
                    initializer[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return getSortedString(initializer);
    }

    //this method is for to keep sortString on new String
    private static String getSortedString(String initializer[]) {
        for (String s : initializer) {
            sortedString += s;
        }
        return sortedString;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

@Vishal Tiwari, on your code that was added on comment by you, you can add these codes inside `if(a>0){...}` condition:

```
    if (a > 0) {
        StringBuffer Sorted = new StringBuffer(new String(charArray));
        return Integer.parseInt("" + Sorted.reverse());
    }
```

and remove these useless lines:

```
    while(a!=0){
        size++;
        a /= 10;
    }
```

Comment: one more thing, because of the naming convention, use `sorted` instead of `Sorted` as other declared variable names on your code such as `str` , `charArray`, etc. Read more  [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)